# Volume projection on a video

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, opengl

I developed a calibration tool on QT for my work. I already have the intrinsic parameters for our cameras, and it detects extrinsic parameters using a checkerboard. The thing is, my boss would like to add the possibility to show a 3D model next to the table where the checkerboard is when it's detected. I use an OpenCV widget to stream, but I don't know how I can show the stream together with the 3D model while taking into account the extrinsics.

For now, I managed to do this :

```
void camCalibration::startVisualisationAR()
{
    this->initializeVisualizers();
    this->loadXraydevice();

    //! Wait to get initial data
    boost::posix_time::milliseconds waiting_for_data(100);
    boost::this_thread::sleep(waiting_for_data);

    int count=0;
    while( m_ARVisuStarted )
    {
        //! Get color imgs from shared buffer and show it
        for( int dIdx = 0; dIdx < m_numCameras; dIdx++)
        {
            //! Color current color 
            m_sharedDataMutexes[dIdx]->lock();
                m_colorImagesLocal[ dIdx ] = m_imagesPerCamera[dIdx][0]->clone();
            m_sharedDataMutexes[ dIdx ]->unlock();

            if( m_colorImagesLocal[ dIdx ].rows != 0)
            {
                if( xaware_demo_utils::openCV2VTK( m_colorImagesLocal[ dIdx ], m_colorImagesData[ dIdx ] ))
                {
                    m_colorImagesData[ dIdx ]->Modified();

                    m_colorImagesActor[ dIdx ]->SetInput( m_colorImagesData[ dIdx ] );
                    m_colorImagesActor[ dIdx ]->SetOpacity(1);

                    //m_virtualImagesActor[ dIdx ]->SetInput( m_virtualImagesData[ dIdx ] );

                    if(count < m_numCameras)
                    {
                       m_xRayDevice_renderers[ dIdx ]->AddActor( m_colorImagesActor[ dIdx ] );
                       m_xRayDevice_renderers[ dIdx ]->AddActor( m_xRayDevice_actor );

                       vtkSmartPointer<vtkCamera> camera = m_xRayDevice_renderers[ dIdx ]->GetActiveCamera();
                       m_xRayDevice_renderers[ dIdx ]->ResetCamera();
                       camera->Zoom(1.7);

                       m_xRayDevice_renderWindows[ dIdx ]->Render();

                       count++;
                    }

                    //! Get output AR image in CV format
                    vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> ar_output = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New();
                    ar_output = xaware_demo_utils::vtkWindowToImage( m_xRayDevice_renderWindows[ dIdx ]);

                    m_outputARImages[ dIdx ] = xaware_demo_utils::vtkToOpenCV( ar_output );

                    //! Convert color channels
                    cv::cvtColor( m_outputARImages[ dIdx ], m_outputARImages[ dIdx ], CV_BGRA2RGBA );
                    cv::cvtColor( m_outputARImages[ dIdx ], m_outputARImages[ dIdx ], CV_RGBA2RGB );

                    //! Sent AR images to GUI
                    m_sharedOutputDataMutexes[ dIdx ]->lock();
                        *m_outputSharedImages[ dIdx ] = m_outputARImages[ dIdx ].clone();
                    m_sharedOutputDataMutexes[ dIdx ]->unlock();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //! Release memory
    this->closeRenderWindows();
}
```

I can't show much more because of confidentiality reasons.

Here is the room with the checkerboard while performing the calibration:

[image: Calibration ongoing]

Then, I use a checkbox to activate the AR visualization. For now, I can just show the 3D model (an xray device I replaced by a nice crocodile statue, to avoid any problems) next to the cameras inputs:

[image: Showing 3D model with the videos]

Any idea how I could limit renderer view to the video actor rather than both actors? And how can I set the scale and position of the volume on the image depending on the camera's parameters?